# How can I modify a Folder's columns? Not the "Name" column, but other ones such as Year, Date Released, etc

Tags: external-hard-drive, file-management, music

[Screenshot of my folder I need help with](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hp5PV.png)

Okay so to be a little more detailed with my issue. I like to be EXTRA organized with my music in my external hard drive. That being said, I have a Music Folder that has Sub-Folders of all the Album-Artists I've collected over the time. In those Sub-Folders are Sub-Sub-Folders of their Albums, EP's, Artworks, etc. and finally I have Sub-Sub-Sub-Folders in those folders as well, so in my Albums Sub-Folder, you will see multiple albums from the specified Artist, and I wanted to have a column showing "Date Release" so I knew the oldest and newest Albums from the specified Artist. However, on the Folder, it only shows the "Title, Date Modified, and File Type". I can add more columns however I can't rename them so I tried right-clicking the folder that has the Album I'd like to work on and on the Properties section, the only things that happen to pop up in the Properties is "General, Sharing, Security, Previous Versions, and Customize" and none of these have the option to modify columns. Unlike a Music File, you can edit pretty much everything. On this Album File I just want to add the column "Date Release". I feel like I'm missing something very minor or maybe it can only be modified on Music Files. Please help. Thanks.

[This is the screenshot of the Album Folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3vR7x.png)

[And this is the final screenshot of the music file I can edit](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GqcIi.png)

Thanks again.
- Joseph

Answer (score 0):

As Microsoft obviously blocks the access/api to create additional folder properties there is no on board tool or known 3rd party shell extension doing what you want. There are only workarounds.
Create the complete folder structure as links and use the property field comment (only available for links) to store your release date. In explorer you have to activate the column comment and now you can sort with comment (aka release date). Clicking on the links jumps then to the real folder. 
The second workaround is changing manually (or via batch) the created date to the release date of the album, for this task you can use Windows PowerShell or third party apps like [Attribute Changer](https://www.petges.lu/) 
If you are really good in C++/Win10 development you can try to write your own shell extension probably the hit for thousands of people waiting for such a tool.